# SQL return similar rows

Tags: sql

I have the below table (let's call it "xxx") from a SQL query. From "xxx" I'm looking to find all of the rows where any given row has a corresponding row where column A is the same, column B is different, column C is the same, and column D is the same - matching all of the requirements. So in the below set of rows I only want the last two rows where in those 2 rows, D is the same for both rows, C is the same, B is different, and A is the same. What is the easiest way to return this?

```
A           B       C       D
100000600   04080   127 640288
100000600   04080   127 641034
100000700   04080   127 659175
100000700   04095   128 664697
100000700   18192   128 676507
100000700   04095   128 676507
```

Comment: In addition to adding the information noted below, please be sure to indicate what flavor of SQL you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good application of the `exists` clause:

```
select *
from xxxx x1
where exists (select 1
              from xxxx x2
              where x2.a = x1.a and
                    x2.b <> x1.b and
                    x2.c = x1.c and
                    x2.d = x1.d
             )
```

---

(*Gordon, I apologize for hijacking your answer. I was unable to submit my answer, because the question was closed while I was editing it.*)

The query with the EXISTS clause will return the specified result set. Another way to get an equivalent result is use an inline view, to get columns A, C and D where there is more than one value of B, and then join that to the table, to return the rows. e.g.

```
SELECT t.A
     , t.B
     , t.C
     , t.D
  FROM ( 
         SELECT r.A
              , r.C
              , r.D
           FROM mytable r
          GROUP
             BY r.A
              , r.C
              , r.D
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.B) > 1
       ) s
  JOIN mytable t
    ON t.A = s.A
   AND t.C = s.C
   AND t.D = s.D
 ORDER
    BY t.A, t.C, t.D, t.B
```

Comment: +1 using an EXISTS predicate is arguably the easiest.